# scrollbar disappeared when i add mouse to mac at first time

Tags: html, css, macos, scrollbar

Scrollbar disappeared when I add mouse to mac at first time.
please look at this links.

[demo link](http://bit.ly/1WuSqcj)

When I add mouse to my mac, scroll bar disappeared and a white color box coming right top corner. I do not know why. firefox working fine. chrome safari, and opera i.e had this issue. After refresh the page i could see scrollbar. Help me if you know/face this issue before.

screenshots here... who does not able to understand my issue.

screen shot one after i insert mouse to mac machine scroll disappeared and getting square box right top corner:

[image]

after I refresh the page i get see scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the setting in the preferences. By default, the scroll bar is hidden with mac products.

Comment: Yes, I know that. but what ever the setting we have, we don't force website visitors to change their mac settings. i am trying to find any alternatives with html, css. may be we can use javascript or jquery, but will find the solution. Link updated as per my current requirement. thank you for your reply @sburke0708.

Answer (score 0):

Odds are if a user is using a Mac, they're already aware of this and it's considered a feature to them.

But, if you really need it, try using the [webkit css pseudo selector](https://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/) `::-webkit-scrollbar`

This will only work in Safari and Chrome.

Comment: Its good think @dethstrobe. I tried it. ::-webkit-scrollbar { -webkit-appearance: none; width: 0; } it helps me, but what exactly happening here is this code completely hiding scrollbar with the help of width 0. there is no scrollbar now even if i am scrollable area, but i can scroll the chat block. when i remove mouse from mac its scroll bar enabled and right chat content hiding design breaking issue now. thinking about it.

Comment: if you have mac and time you can test here    http://codepen.io/vulchivijay/pen/XdpgpY solution will help me.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce that white box that you're talking about. I'm using 10.11.3, Chome 49.0.2623.87, Safari 9.0.3, and Firefox 44.0.2

Comment: it only appears fist time of page load. remove mouse refresh the page, insert mouse to see the white box actually scrollbar disappear. and if you want to check again. we have to do same thing remove mouse refresh page and insert mouse.

Comment: screenshot available in main content. you can see this issue here also https://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/ chrome version.

Comment: I comes to conclude this question myself. its Mac browsers rendering issue. There is no way to fix this issue with html, css, javascript.

thank you for reply guys.